# Sending large javascript array to Web API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

I am struggling with this issue for 2 days...

I have a JavaScript array (20,000K rows and 41 columns). It was originally received in javaScript through an ajax call as shown below,

```
var dataArray = [];
var dataRequest = {};
            dataRequest.SearchCondition = 'some value'; 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "api/GetData/ProcessRequest",              
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                crossDomain: false,
                data: dataRequest ,
                success: function (response) {
                  dataArray = response; 
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   dataArray = null;
                }
            });
```

In the application, the user will verify the data and send it back to Web API method.

I am trying to send the same data back (dataArray) to web api method but, it fails. Please see the code below,

Option 1: (failed - the request did not hit web api method)

```
 var dataArrayJsonStr = JSON.stringify(dataArray);                     

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/SendData/ProcessRequest",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'dataValue':dataArrayJsonStr },
        success: function (response) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown)
        }
    });
```

In IE 8, I am getting 'out of memory' exception popup. (most of our application users still have IE 8)

In Chrome, it crashes.

Option 2 tried: (don't know how to read the value)

I tried to send the same value to web api through XmllHttpRequest

```
var dataArrayJsonStr = JSON.stringify(dataArr);
            var xmlRequest;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();                
            }
            xmlRequest.open("POST", "api/SendData/ProcessRequest", false);
            xmlRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/text');
            xmlRequest.send("dataValue=" + dataArrayJsonStr);
```

Using Chrome, I am able to post the data successfully to Web API, I am seeing the content-length as '128180309'. But, I don't see the values. How do i get the values in Web API?

Please suggest me how to send large data back to web api from javascript.

Thanks,
Vim

Answer (score 1):

I think you create overhead, maybe I wrong, you can edit me.
Did you really need send back all datas back or you just need send modified data? 
Because in real life hard to imagine that user will review 20.000 of rows.

Good example is ExtJS stores, you can see example [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/grid/paging.html)
Key thing of stores that they send back to the server only modified or deleted data, it save browser, network and server resources.

Comment: I have to send all the data back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add more memory for API or more time excecution, also you can try return data in more small parts. Defining the number of parts to send.

Comment: Can you provide me code sample or refer to an article to return data in small parts?

Comment: I will search an article, but is more of logic, you obtain length from array then
var numbers_object = object / 1000( registres);
and execute the response with each or for
I search a example or create for give a idea

Comment: In this case, how do I receive the data in Web API and make them to a single object?

Comment: I think that is something like this:
global array= [][]

function get_data(){
   part = request.part;
   part_data = request.data;
   end = part_data.length * part;
   count = end - part_data.length;
   for(count; count <= end; count++){
       global array[count][part_data[count]];
   }

}

Anyway you need check this logic with your code, but I think that this can run

Comment: If the user only check the info but don't update nothing, in your api save the same data before sending in a global variable, and with the response of the user, use this data save. This only if user don't update data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to send the data by chunks?
I mean, you need to split it in small pieces and perform multiple number of requests.

For example, it can be like:

```
--HELLO SERVER. STARTING TRANSMITION FOR DATA SET #177151--  
PIECE 1/13  
PIECE 2/13  
...  
PIECE 13/13  
--BUE SERVER--
```

So, it will take some time, but you can send any amounts of data without memory problems. If you're struggling with it for 2 days, I think you got some time to code it :)

**UPD1**: Client code example.

Here's an example of client code. This is a simple chunking algorithm.
Have to say I **didn't test** it, because it would take a lot of time to represent your situation.

So, you should read it and get the point.
You have a simple function, that takes you whole data set and callbacks for each response (to update your progress bar, e.g.), for successful finish and for error.

Hope, it will help you to make some problems.
Also, I can help you to build architecture on the server-side, but I need to know what technologies do you use.

```
function sendData(data, onEach, onFinish, onError) {
    var CHUNK_SIZE = 1000;
    var isFailed = false;
    var chunkNum = 0;
    var chunk, chunkStart, chunkEnd;

    while(data.length + CHUNK_SIZE > chunkNum * CHUNK_SIZE) {
        if(isFailed) {
            return;
        }
        chunkStart = chunkNum * CHUNK_SIZE;
        chunkEnd   = chunkStart + CHUNK_SIZE + 1;

        chunk = {
            num: chunkNum,
            data: data.slice(chunkStart, chunkEnd)
        };

        ajaxCall(chunk);
        chunkNum++;
    }

    function ajaxCall(data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api/GetData/ProcessRequest",              
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            data: dataRequest ,
            success: function (response) {
                onEach(data, response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                isFailed = true;
                onError(arguments);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Also, you can send the number of current chunk with whole request and send all requests asynchronously. Then server will able to construct right set of data in right order when last piece will be recieved

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did not try sending the data by chunks. Can you provide me code sample?

Comment: You also can modify the code to send "hello message" and tell the server, how many chunks does he should to receive and give each separate transmission a uniq id that generates on the server-side as response on the "hello message"

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. I will try it today. Earlier, I tried using Blob in HTML5 and it worked perfectly in Chrome but not in IE8 as it is not supported. One question though... in the ProcessRequest method, how do we combine the chunks in to a complete object?

Comment: If chunks were sended asynchronously, as in my example, server should know, how many parts it should receive and after all parts is received, you have to sort them in the right order (every request contains number of part) and combine if you need.

Comment: And why can't you send only the difference between data that user made with "client version" of data and server version?

I mean, user takes 20k rows and he changes just a few of them. Why can't you send back only changed rows and let server know that other rows wasn't changed?

Like Version Control Systems send only the [difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) of files instead of whole file